# What is meant by 'MyType = Int => Boolean'

Tags: scala

What is meant by below scala declaration :

```
type MyType = Int => Boolean
```

Here is my understanding :

I'm declaring a new type 'MyType' but what is meant by the higher order function 'Int => Boolean'

Comment: Note that `Int => Boolean` is _not_ a higher order function (not even if the snippet stems from [Coursera's](http://www.coursera.org/course/progfun) "Week 2: Higher Order Functions" assignment ;-))

Comment: @netzwerg yes, it seems im finding even the 'simple' stuff difficult.

Comment: Don't worry, this one's really simple: Higher order functions are functions which either take another function as their input parameter, or return/output another function ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function))

Comment: I'm taking that course just now, this beauty declaration is a bit hard to undertand at first. This post gave me a good undertanding of what really happens with the fun set, this sort of pieces of code help to understand how useful and different Scala is from "impertive" languages ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not so much declaring a new *type* as declaring a new type *alias*.  They're still the same type: but the alias lets your write it a little more succinctly.

`Int => Boolean` is the type of a function that takes one argument, an Int, and returns a Boolean.

For example, a function like "greater than 5" could have type `Int => Boolean`:

```
type MyType = Int => Boolean
val greaterThan5: MyType = (x: Int) => x > 5
greaterThan5(7)  // true
```

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, the following compiles:

```
type MyType = Int => Boolean
def positive(x: Int) = x > 0
val fun: MyType = positive
fun(42)  //yields true
```

Here you declare type alias saying that `MyType` equivalent to a function taking `Int` and returning `Boolean`. Then you create a method matching such declaration. Finally you assign this method to a variable of `MyType` type. It compiles and works just fine.

Note that this is just an *alias*, not a new type:

```
trait MyType2 extends (Int => Boolean)
val fun2: MyType2 = positive _
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int => Boolean
 required: MyType2
       val fun2: MyType2 = positive _
                           ^
```